# PHP get input name dynamically

Tags: php, post, input

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="denumireArcStanga" id="denumireArcStanga" /> 
<input type="text" name="denumireArcDreapta" id="denumireArcDreapta" />
```

PHP (this is the standard inputs name):

```
$arcDeStanga = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['$variableArcStanga']);
$arcDeDreapta = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['$variableArcDreapta']);
```

Javascript (an ajax result return result.denumireArcStanga and result.denumireArcDreapta from another separate PHP script):

```
document.getElementById("denumireArcStanga").setAttribute("name",result.denumireArcStanga);
    document.getElementById("denumireArcDreapta").setAttribute("name",result.denumireArcDreapta);
```

With js, the name of inputs are changing and I need to get in `$_POST`, the name it is actually written in those inputs.

I thought at a solution with 2 switches like, but not sure if it is the correct way?

```
switch($variableArcStanga)
{
      case "VL105-6-3250PS":
            $VL10563250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL105-6-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL55-1-3250PS":
            $VL5513250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL55-1-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL60-1-3250PS":
            return $VL6013250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL60-1-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL60-2-3250PS":
            $VL6023250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL60-2-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL65-2-3250PS":
            $VL6523250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL65-2-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL70-2-3250PS":
            $VL7023250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL70-2-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL70-3-3250PS":
            $VL7033250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL70-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL75-3-3250PS":
            $VL7533250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL75-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL80-3-3250PS":
            $VL8033250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL80-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL85-3-3250PS":
            $VL8533250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL85-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL85-6-3250PS":
            $VL8563250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL85-6-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL90-3-3250PS":
            $VL9033250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL90-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL90-6-3250PS":
            $VL9063250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL90-6-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL95-3-3250PS":
            $VL9533250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL95-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VL95-6-3250PS":
            $VL9563250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VL95-6-3250PS']);
      break;
}

switch($variableArcDreapta)
{
      case "VR105-6-3250PS":
            $VR10563250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR105-6-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR55-1-3250PS":
            $VR5513250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR55-1-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR60-1-3250PS":
            $VR6013250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR60-1-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR60-2-3250PS":
            $VR6023250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR60-2-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR65-2-3250PS":
            $VR6523250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR65-2-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR70-2-3250PS":
            $VR7023250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR70-2-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR70-3-3250PS":
            $VR7033250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR70-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR75-3-3250PS":
            $VR7533250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR75-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR80-3-3250PS":
            $VR8033250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR80-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR85-3-3250PS":
            $VR8533250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR85-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR85-6-3250PS":
            $VR8563250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR85-6-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR90-3-3250PS":
            $VR9033250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR90-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR90-6-3250PS":
            $VR9063250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR90-6-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR95-3-3250PS":
            $VR9533250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR95-3-3250PS']);
      break;
      case "VR95-6-3250PS":
            $VR9563250PS = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['VR95-6-3250PS']);
      break;
}
```

For example, the inputs name can be:

```
<input type="text" name="VL105-6-3250PS" id="denumireArcStanga" /> 
<input type="text" name="VR105-6-3250PS" id="denumireArcDreapta" />
```

I need to get the current name for use in `$_POST`. 
How can I do that? It doesn`t work this way.

Comment: what is wrong with `$_POST[$variableArcStanga]`? This should do what you want.

Comment: Man, you are masochist, really :)

Comment: I recomment you to send array of fields to server like `VL105-6-3250PS[]` then simply iterate it is loop: `foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {}`

Comment: Can you please give me an example?